# Set req.session in mongoose model

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, express-session

Hey guys I am trying to make session setting very easy by handling all values that are set in my User model. How can I achieve the following:

```
userSchema.methods.setSession = function () {
    var user = req.session.user; //create the session object

    //set any values I want here
    user.firstName = this.firstName;
    user.lastName = this.lastName;
    user.school = this.school;
    user.email = this.email;
    user.admin = this.admin;
    user.moderator = this.moderator;
}
```

The problem I am having is that req is not defined. Is there a way to access req in here?

Comment: Sure: pass it as an argument...

Comment: @robertklep I tried that and it says cannot read property session of undefined

Comment: In that case, there's something else going wrong, like the session middleware not being declared before the route in which you call `.setSession()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I utilize mongoose to grab all data for the user. Then I pass that data to the setSession method and set all desired session data. Now if I need a new session variable I can just update it in my User Model.

Here is my solution. In my route I put:

```
user = new User();
userData = someUserObjectIPulledFromMongo;

//pass user data to setSession function
user.setSession(userData ,req, function (data) {

});
```

The method I made within my User model:

```
userSchema.methods.setSession = function (user, req, callback) {
    //specify any desired session data in here
    sessionData = {
        firstName: user.firstName,
        lastName: user.lastName,
        email: user.email,
    }
    //pass temporary session object to req.session
    req.session.user = sessionData;
    callback(true);
}
```